# How to implement a http proxy for localhost in windows?

Tags: c++, proxy

So that all browser request(no matter firefox or IE) will be sending out via the proxy automatically without any configuration.

Is it kind of thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want with the proxy? Fiddler is automaticly set as a proxy for ie when it is active. Firefox needs manual configuration. But there is no traffic possible as long fiddler is active without using the proxy.

[fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: After some googling I find what I'm trying to do is similar to NDIS...http://www.ndis.com/  .But still far from getting started...